# How can integrate multiple functions into my post route and pass on objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to integrate the Stripe api with my project. I am already collecting all needed data and sending it to my post route.
I want to make charges to a customer and have all functions to do so, if I would invoke them all one by one. How can I integrate all functions into my post route, so it is processed all at once. Also, I do not how to pass data from one function to another, so in the end there would be a function chain with the same data. My post route and functions:

```
     router.post("/checkout", async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.redirect("/shopping-cart");
  }
  // You can return promise directly
  let createCustomer = function () {
    var param ={};
    param.email = req.body.email;
    param.name= req.body.name;
    param.description ="";
    return stripe.customers.create(param, function (err, customer) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);
      }
      if (customer) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(customer, null, 2));
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });


  };

  let createToken = function () {
    let param ={};

    param.card = {
      number: req.body.card,
      exp_month: req.body.exp_month,
      exp_year: req.body.exp_year,
      cvc: req.body.security
  }
    return stripe.tokens.create(param, function (err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);
        console.log(param);
      }
      if (token) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(token, null, 2));
        console.log(req.body);
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });
  };




  let addCardToCustomer = function () {
    console.log(createdCustomer);
   return stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, {source: token.id}, function (err, card) {
     if (err) {
       console.log("err:" + err);
       console.log(param);
     }
     if (card) {
       console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(card, null, 2));
     } else {
       console.log("something went wrong");
     }
   });
 };



  try {
    const createdCustomer = await createCustomer(); // promise 1
    const createdToken = await createToken();
    const addedCardToCustomer = await addCardToCustomer(createdCustomer,createdToken ); // await addCardToCustomer(createdCustumer); to pass created customer info to next request
    // const chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID = await chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID(); // promise 3
    // more things...

    res.send("success");

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`error ${e}`)
  };



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can chain your promises... / use async await and do one task at time in order you need. you can also pass data from one promise to another as shown below.

```js
// You can return promise directly
let createCustomer = function () {
  return stripe.customers.create(param);
}

let addCardToCustomer = function(){
    return stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id,{source:token.id});
};

// or use async /await
let chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID = async function () {
  const data = await stripe.charges.create(param).catch((e) => { console.log(`error ${e}`); throw e })
  // do something with data
  
  return data;     
}

let chargeCustomerThroughTokenID = async function () {
  const data = await stripe.charges.create(param).catch((e) => { console.log(`error ${e}`); throw e });
  // do something with data

  return data;     
}

router.post("/checkout", async function(req, res, next) { // Async
  if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.redirect("/shopping-cart");
  }
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
  
  try {
    const createdCustumer = await createCustomer(); // promise 1
    const addCardToCustomer = await addCardToCustomer(); // await addCardToCustomer(createdCustumer); to pass created customer info to next request
    const chargCustomer = await chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID(); // promise 3
    // more things...
    
    res.send(...);
  
  }
  catch(e) {
     console.log(`error ${e}`)
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so far. So I tried your suggestion with the return promise directly variant, but i am getting the following  error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createCustomer' before initialization

Did I do something wrong? You know whats up with that?

Comment: Yes... if you just use the code as it is it won't work. you declare `let createCustomer = function () {` at the bottom. But it's being used before it's declared. So you need to move to top. Updated the answer

Comment: Yes this makes actually sense. Now my new problem is:
addCardToCustomer is still being invoked as second. Also, createdCustomer is not defined when trying it to pass it on. Ill update the new code in my question

Comment: as second? if your problem is different and not the same as original then you'd need to ask a new question. and expand/focus on the stripe API create part